# Ubuntu will only boot to GUI after recovering journal

Tags: boot, gui, 17.04

I recently installed the new 17.04 version with the GNOME GUI, and I'm having an weird issue when i reboot the system: the black screen =(

I already tried to figure it out what is happening, and I believe the cause could be some missing kernel parameter. The only way to avoid the black screen is forcing the shutdown (pressing the power button), then, in the next
boot, i will see the message "recovering journal", then everything will work just fine, no flickering, no nothing.

I don't know if this is normal in the GNOME GUI, but the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>) doesn't work at all, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> will send me to the login screen when I'm logged, maybe the two problems are related?

I'm using a GTX 1060 (6GB) and the driver version is 375.39.

Thanks.